# LINK : fatal error LNK1104: cannot open file 'msvcprt.lib'

Tags: python, visual-c++

trying to install tiny-cuda-nn\bindings\torch package in python, but encountered an issue

**Here are the env:**
cuda_11.8.0_522.06_windows.exe

cmake 3.23.1

python 3.10.10

win11

cudnn-windows-x86_64-8.9.6.50_cuda11-archive.zip

**steps:**
`cd d:\aigc\`

`git clone --recursive https://github.com/nvlabs/tiny-cuda-nn`

`open Visual Studio 2022 Developer Command Prompt v17.8.3`

`cd d:\aigc\tiny-cuda-nn`

`cmake . -B build -DCMAKE_BUILD_TYPE=RelWithDebInfo`

`cmake --build build --config RelWithDebInfo -j`

**logs for cmake:**

```
d:\AIGC\tiny-cuda-nn>cmake . -B build -DCMAKE_BUILD_TYPE=RelWithDebInfo
-- Building for: Visual Studio 17 2022
-- The CXX compiler identification is MSVC 19.38.33133.0
-- The CUDA compiler identification is NVIDIA 11.8.89
-- Detecting CXX compiler ABI info
-- Detecting CXX compiler ABI info - done
-- Check for working CXX compiler: D:/Program Files/Microsoft Visual Studio/2022/Community/VC/Tools/MSVC/14.38.33130/bin/Hostx64/x64/cl.exe - skipped
-- Detecting CXX compile features
-- Detecting CXX compile features - done
-- Detecting CUDA compiler ABI info
-- Detecting CUDA compiler ABI info - done
-- Check for working CUDA compiler: C:/Program Files/NVIDIA GPU Computing Toolkit/CUDA/v11.8/bin/nvcc.exe - skipped
-- Detecting CUDA compile features
-- Detecting CUDA compile features - done
-- Obtained CUDA architectures automatically from installed GPUs
-- Targeting CUDA architectures: 86
-- Module support is disabled.
-- Version: 9.1.1
-- Build type: RelWithDebInfo
-- Configuring done (8.2s)
-- Generating done (0.0s)
-- Build files have been written to: D:/AIGC/tiny-cuda-nn/build

d:\AIGC\tiny-cuda-nn>cmake --build build --config RelWithDebInfo -j
MSBuild version 17.8.3+195e7f5a3 for .NET Framework

  1>Checking Build System
  Building Custom Rule D:/AIGC/tiny-cuda-nn/dependencies/fmt/CMakeLists.txt
  format.cc
  os.cc
  fmt.vcxproj -> D:\AIGC\tiny-cuda-nn\build\dependencies\fmt\RelWithDebInfo\fmt.lib
  Building Custom Rule D:/AIGC/tiny-cuda-nn/CMakeLists.txt
  Compiling CUDA source file ..\src\cutlass_mlp.cu...
  Compiling CUDA source file ..\src\encoding.cu...
  Compiling CUDA source file ..\src\common_host.cu...
  Compiling CUDA source file ..\src\cpp_api.cu...
  Compiling CUDA source file ..\src\loss.cu...
  Compiling CUDA source file ..\src\network.cu...
  Compiling CUDA source file ..\src\fully_fused_mlp.cu...
  Compiling CUDA source file ..\src\optimizer.cu...
  Compiling CUDA source file ..\src\reduce_sum.cu...
  Compiling CUDA source file ..\src\object.cu...

  D:\AIGC\tiny-cuda-nn\build>"C:\Program Files\NVIDIA GPU Computing Toolkit\CUDA\v11.8\bin\nvcc.exe"  --use-local-env -
  ccbin "D:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio\2022\Community\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.38.33130\bin\HostX64\x64" -x cu   -I"
  D:\AIGC\tiny-cuda-nn\include" -I"D:\AIGC\tiny-cuda-nn\dependencies" -I"D:\AIGC\tiny-cuda-nn\dependencies\cutlass\incl
  ude" -I"D:\AIGC\tiny-cuda-nn\dependencies\cutlass\tools\util\include" -I"D:\AIGC\tiny-cuda-nn\dependencies\fmt\includ
  e" -I"C:\Program Files\NVIDIA GPU Computing Toolkit\CUDA\v11.8\include"     --keep-dir x64\RelWithDebInfo  -maxrregco
  unt=0  --machine 64 --compile -cudart static -std=c++14 --generate-code=arch=compute_86,code=[compute_86,sm_86] --ext
  ended-lambda --expt-relaxed-constexpr -Xcompiler="/EHsc -Zi -Ob1 /bigobj"   -D_WINDOWS -DNDEBUG -DTCNN_MIN_GPU_ARCH=8
  6 -D"CMAKE_INTDIR=\"RelWithDebInfo\"" -D_MBCS -DWIN32 -D_WINDOWS -D_CRT_SECURE_NO_WARNINGS -DNDEBUG -DTCNN_MIN_GPU_AR
  CH=86 -D"CMAKE_INTDIR=\"RelWithDebInfo\"" -Xcompiler "/EHsc /W1 /nologo /O2 /FdD:\AIGC\tiny-cuda-nn\build\RelWithDebI
  nfo\tiny-cuda-nn.pdb /FS /Zi  /MD /GR" -o tiny-cuda-nn.dir\RelWithDebInfo\cpp_api.obj "D:\AIGC\tiny-cuda-nn\src\cpp_a
  pi.cu"

  D:\AIGC\tiny-cuda-nn\build>"C:\Program Files\NVIDIA GPU Computing Toolkit\CUDA\v11.8\bin\nvcc.exe"  --use-local-env -
  ccbin "D:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio\2022\Community\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.38.33130\bin\HostX64\x64" -x cu   -I"
  D:\AIGC\tiny-cuda-nn\include" -I"D:\AIGC\tiny-cuda-nn\dependencies" -I"D:\AIGC\tiny-cuda-nn\dependencies\cutlass\incl
  ude" -I"D:\AIGC\tiny-cuda-nn\dependencies\cutlass\tools\util\include" -I"D:\AIGC\tiny-cuda-nn\dependencies\fmt\includ
  e" -I"C:\Program Files\NVIDIA GPU Computing Toolkit\CUDA\v11.8\include"     --keep-dir x64\RelWithDebInfo  -maxrregco
  unt=0  --machine 64 --compile -cudart static -std=c++14 --generate-code=arch=compute_86,code=[compute_86,sm_86] --ext
  ended-lambda --expt-relaxed-constexpr -Xcompiler="/EHsc -Zi -Ob1 /bigobj"   -D_WINDOWS -DNDEBUG -DTCNN_MIN_GPU_ARCH=8
  6 -D"CMAKE_INTDIR=\"RelWithDebInfo\"" -D_MBCS -DWIN32 -D_WINDOWS -D_CRT_SECURE_NO_WARNINGS -DNDEBUG -DTCNN_MIN_GPU_AR
  CH=86 -D"CMAKE_INTDIR=\"RelWithDebInfo\"" -Xcompiler "/EHsc /W1 /nologo /O2 /FdD:\AIGC\tiny-cuda-nn\build\RelWithDebI
  nfo\tiny-cuda-nn.pdb /FS /Zi  /MD /GR" -o tiny-cuda-nn.dir\RelWithDebInfo\cutlass_mlp.obj "D:\AIGC\tiny-cuda-nn\src\c
  utlass_mlp.cu"

  D:\AIGC\tiny-cuda-nn\build>"C:\Program Files\NVIDIA GPU Computing Toolkit\CUDA\v11.8\bin\nvcc.exe"  --use-local-env -
  ccbin "D:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio\2022\Community\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.38.33130\bin\HostX64\x64" -x cu   -I"
  D:\AIGC\tiny-cuda-nn\include" -I"D:\AIGC\tiny-cuda-nn\dependencies" -I"D:\AIGC\tiny-cuda-nn\dependencies\cutlass\incl
  ude" -I"D:\AIGC\tiny-cuda-nn\dependencies\cutlass\tools\util\include" -I"D:\AIGC\tiny-cuda-nn\dependencies\fmt\includ
  e" -I"C:\Program Files\NVIDIA GPU Computing Toolkit\CUDA\v11.8\include"     --keep-dir x64\RelWithDebInfo  -maxrregco
  unt=0  --machine 64 --compile -cudart static -std=c++14 --generate-code=arch=compute_86,code=[compute_86,sm_86] --ext
  ended-lambda --expt-relaxed-constexpr -Xcompiler="/EHsc -Zi -Ob1 /bigobj"   -D_WINDOWS -DNDEBUG -DTCNN_MIN_GPU_ARCH=8
  6 -D"CMAKE_INTDIR=\"RelWithDebInfo\"" -D_MBCS -DWIN32 -D_WINDOWS -D_CRT_SECURE_NO_WARNINGS -DNDEBUG -DTCNN_MIN_GPU_AR
  CH=86 -D"CMAKE_INTDIR=\"RelWithDebInfo\"" -Xcompiler "/EHsc /W1 /nologo /O2 /FdD:\AIGC\tiny-cuda-nn\build\RelWithDebI
  nfo\tiny-cuda-nn.pdb /FS /Zi  /MD /GR" -o tiny-cuda-nn.dir\RelWithDebInfo\common_host.obj "D:\AIGC\tiny-cuda-nn\src\c
  ommon_host.cu"

  D:\AIGC\tiny-cuda-nn\build>"C:\Program Files\NVIDIA GPU Computing Toolkit\CUDA\v11.8\bin\nvcc.exe"  --use-local-env -
  ccbin "D:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio\2022\Community\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.38.33130\bin\HostX64\x64" -x cu   -I"
  D:\AIGC\tiny-cuda-nn\include" -I"D:\AIGC\tiny-cuda-nn\dependencies" -I"D:\AIGC\tiny-cuda-nn\dependencies\cutlass\incl
  ude" -I"D:\AIGC\tiny-cuda-nn\dependencies\cutlass\tools\util\include" -I"D:\AIGC\tiny-cuda-nn\dependencies\fmt\includ
  e" -I"C:\Program Files\NVIDIA GPU Computing Toolkit\CUDA\v11.8\include"     --keep-dir x64\RelWithDebInfo  -maxrregco
  unt=0  --machine 64 --compile -cudart static -std=c++14 --generate-code=arch=compute_86,code=[compute_86,sm_86] --ext
  ended-lambda --expt-relaxed-constexpr -Xcompiler="/EHsc -Zi -Ob1 /bigobj"   -D_WINDOWS -DNDEBUG -DTCNN_MIN_GPU_ARCH=8
  6 -D"CMAKE_INTDIR=\"RelWithDebInfo\"" -D_MBCS -DWIN32 -D_WINDOWS -D_CRT_SECURE_NO_WARNINGS -DNDEBUG -DTCNN_MIN_GPU_AR
  CH=86 -D"CMAKE_INTDIR=\"RelWithDebInfo\"" -Xcompiler "/EHsc /W1 /nologo /O2 /FdD:\AIGC\tiny-cuda-nn\build\RelWithDebI
  nfo\tiny-cuda-nn.pdb /FS /Zi  /MD /GR" -o tiny-cuda-nn.dir\RelWithDebInfo\encoding.obj "D:\AIGC\tiny-cuda-nn\src\enco
  ding.cu"

  D:\AIGC\tiny-cuda-nn\build>"C:\Program Files\NVIDIA GPU Computing Toolkit\CUDA\v11.8\bin\nvcc.exe"  --use-local-env -
  ccbin "D:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio\2022\Community\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.38.33130\bin\HostX64\x64" -x cu   -I"
  D:\AIGC\tiny-cuda-nn\include" -I"D:\AIGC\tiny-cuda-nn\dependencies" -I"D:\AIGC\tiny-cuda-nn\dependencies\cutlass\incl
  ude" -I"D:\AIGC\tiny-cuda-nn\dependencies\cutlass\tools\util\include" -I"D:\AIGC\tiny-cuda-nn\dependencies\fmt\includ
  e" -I"C:\Program Files\NVIDIA GPU Computing Toolkit\CUDA\v11.8\include"     --keep-dir x64\RelWithDebInfo  -maxrregco
  unt=0  --machine 64 --compile -cudart static -std=c++14 --generate-code=arch=compute_86,code=[compute_86,sm_86] --ext
  ended-lambda --expt-relaxed-constexpr -Xcompiler="/EHsc -Zi -Ob1 /bigobj"   -D_WINDOWS -DNDEBUG -DTCNN_MIN_GPU_ARCH=8
  6 -D"CMAKE_INTDIR=\"RelWithDebInfo\"" -D_MBCS -DWIN32 -D_WINDOWS -D_CRT_SECURE_NO_WARNINGS -DNDEBUG -DTCNN_MIN_GPU_AR
  CH=86 -D"CMAKE_INTDIR=\"RelWithDebInfo\"" -Xcompiler "/EHsc /W1 /nologo /O2 /FdD:\AIGC\tiny-cuda-nn\build\RelWithDebI
  nfo\tiny-cuda-nn.pdb /FS /Zi  /MD /GR" -o tiny-cuda-nn.dir\RelWithDebInfo\reduce_sum.obj "D:\AIGC\tiny-cuda-nn\src\re
  duce_sum.cu"



  D:\AIGC\tiny-cuda-nn\build>"C:\Program Files\NVIDIA GPU Computing Toolkit\CUDA\v11.8\bin\nvcc.exe"  --use-local-env -
  ccbin "D:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio\2022\Community\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.38.33130\bin\HostX64\x64" -x cu   -I"
  D:\AIGC\tiny-cuda-nn\include" -I"D:\AIGC\tiny-cuda-nn\dependencies" -I"D:\AIGC\tiny-cuda-nn\dependencies\cutlass\incl
  ude" -I"D:\AIGC\tiny-cuda-nn\dependencies\cutlass\tools\util\include" -I"D:\AIGC\tiny-cuda-nn\dependencies\fmt\includ
  e" -I"C:\Program Files\NVIDIA GPU Computing Toolkit\CUDA\v11.8\include"     --keep-dir x64\RelWithDebInfo  -maxrregco
  unt=0  --machine 64 --compile -cudart static -std=c++14 --generate-code=arch=compute_86,code=[compute_86,sm_86] --ext
  ended-lambda --expt-relaxed-constexpr -Xcompiler="/EHsc -Zi -Ob1 /bigobj"   -D_WINDOWS -DNDEBUG -DTCNN_MIN_GPU_ARCH=8
  6 -D"CMAKE_INTDIR=\"RelWithDebInfo\"" -D_MBCS -DWIN32 -D_WINDOWS -D_CRT_SECURE_NO_WARNINGS -DNDEBUG -DTCNN_MIN_GPU_AR
  CH=86 -D"CMAKE_INTDIR=\"RelWithDebInfo\"" -Xcompiler "/EHsc /W1 /nologo /O2 /FdD:\AIGC\tiny-cuda-nn\build\RelWithDebI
  nfo\tiny-cuda-nn.pdb /FS /Zi  /MD /GR" -o tiny-cuda-nn.dir\RelWithDebInfo\loss.obj "D:\AIGC\tiny-cuda-nn\src\loss.cu"

  D:\AIGC\tiny-cuda-nn\build>"C:\Program Files\NVIDIA GPU Computing Toolkit\CUDA\v11.8\bin\nvcc.exe"  --use-local-env -
  ccbin "D:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio\2022\Community\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.38.33130\bin\HostX64\x64" -x cu   -I"
  D:\AIGC\tiny-cuda-nn\include" -I"D:\AIGC\tiny-cuda-nn\dependencies" -I"D:\AIGC\tiny-cuda-nn\dependencies\cutlass\incl
  ude" -I"D:\AIGC\tiny-cuda-nn\dependencies\cutlass\tools\util\include" -I"D:\AIGC\tiny-cuda-nn\dependencies\fmt\includ
  e" -I"C:\Program Files\NVIDIA GPU Computing Toolkit\CUDA\v11.8\include"     --keep-dir x64\RelWithDebInfo  -maxrregco
  unt=0  --machine 64 --compile -cudart static -std=c++14 --generate-code=arch=compute_86,code=[compute_86,sm_86] --ext
  ended-lambda --expt-relaxed-constexpr -Xcompiler="/EHsc -Zi -Ob1 /bigobj"   -D_WINDOWS -DNDEBUG -DTCNN_MIN_GPU_ARCH=8
  6 -D"CMAKE_INTDIR=\"RelWithDebInfo\"" -D_MBCS -DWIN32 -D_WINDOWS -D_CRT_SECURE_NO_WARNINGS -DNDEBUG -DTCNN_MIN_GPU_AR
  CH=86 -D"CMAKE_INTDIR=\"RelWithDebInfo\"" -Xcompiler "/EHsc /W1 /nologo /O2 /FdD:\AIGC\tiny-cuda-nn\build\RelWithDebI
  nfo\tiny-cuda-nn.pdb /FS /Zi  /MD /GR" -o tiny-cuda-nn.dir\RelWithDebInfo\fully_fused_mlp.obj "D:\AIGC\tiny-cuda-nn\s
  rc\fully_fused_mlp.cu"
  D:\AIGC\tiny-cuda-nn\build>"C:\Program Files\NVIDIA GPU Computing Toolkit\CUDA\v11.8\bin\nvcc.exe"  --use-local-env -
  ccbin "D:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio\2022\Community\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.38.33130\bin\HostX64\x64" -x cu   -I"
  D:\AIGC\tiny-cuda-nn\include" -I"D:\AIGC\tiny-cuda-nn\dependencies" -I"D:\AIGC\tiny-cuda-nn\dependencies\cutlass\incl
  ude" -I"D:\AIGC\tiny-cuda-nn\dependencies\cutlass\tools\util\include" -I"D:\AIGC\tiny-cuda-nn\dependencies\fmt\includ
  e" -I"C:\Program Files\NVIDIA GPU Computing Toolkit\CUDA\v11.8\include"     --keep-dir x64\RelWithDebInfo  -maxrregco
  unt=0  --machine 64 --compile -cudart static -std=c++14 --generate-code=arch=compute_86,code=[compute_86,sm_86] --ext
  ended-lambda --expt-relaxed-constexpr -Xcompiler="/EHsc -Zi -Ob1 /bigobj"   -D_WINDOWS -DNDEBUG -DTCNN_MIN_GPU_ARCH=8
  6 -D"CMAKE_INTDIR=\"RelWithDebInfo\"" -D_MBCS -DWIN32 -D_WINDOWS -D_CRT_SECURE_NO_WARNINGS -DNDEBUG -DTCNN_MIN_GPU_AR
  CH=86 -D"CMAKE_INTDIR=\"RelWithDebInfo\"" -Xcompiler "/EHsc /W1 /nologo /O2 /FdD:\AIGC\tiny-cuda-nn\build\RelWithDebI
  nfo\tiny-cuda-nn.pdb /FS /Zi  /MD /GR" -o tiny-cuda-nn.dir\RelWithDebInfo\network.obj "D:\AIGC\tiny-cuda-nn\src\netwo
  rk.cu"

  D:\AIGC\tiny-cuda-nn\build>"C:\Program Files\NVIDIA GPU Computing Toolkit\CUDA\v11.8\bin\nvcc.exe"  --use-local-env -
  ccbin "D:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio\2022\Community\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.38.33130\bin\HostX64\x64" -x cu   -I"
  D:\AIGC\tiny-cuda-nn\include" -I"D:\AIGC\tiny-cuda-nn\dependencies" -I"D:\AIGC\tiny-cuda-nn\dependencies\cutlass\incl
  ude" -I"D:\AIGC\tiny-cuda-nn\dependencies\cutlass\tools\util\include" -I"D:\AIGC\tiny-cuda-nn\dependencies\fmt\includ
  e" -I"C:\Program Files\NVIDIA GPU Computing Toolkit\CUDA\v11.8\include"     --keep-dir x64\RelWithDebInfo  -maxrregco
  unt=0  --machine 64 --compile -cudart static -std=c++14 --generate-code=arch=compute_86,code=[compute_86,sm_86] --ext
  ended-lambda --expt-relaxed-constexpr -Xcompiler="/EHsc -Zi -Ob1 /bigobj"   -D_WINDOWS -DNDEBUG -DTCNN_MIN_GPU_ARCH=8
  6 -D"CMAKE_INTDIR=\"RelWithDebInfo\"" -D_MBCS -DWIN32 -D_WINDOWS -D_CRT_SECURE_NO_WARNINGS -DNDEBUG -DTCNN_MIN_GPU_AR
  CH=86 -D"CMAKE_INTDIR=\"RelWithDebInfo\"" -Xcompiler "/EHsc /W1 /nologo /O2 /FdD:\AIGC\tiny-cuda-nn\build\RelWithDebI
  nfo\tiny-cuda-nn.pdb /FS /Zi  /MD /GR" -o tiny-cuda-nn.dir\RelWithDebInfo\object.obj "D:\AIGC\tiny-cuda-nn\src\object
  .cu"

  D:\AIGC\tiny-cuda-nn\build>"C:\Program Files\NVIDIA GPU Computing Toolkit\CUDA\v11.8\bin\nvcc.exe"  --use-local-env -
  ccbin "D:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio\2022\Community\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.38.33130\bin\HostX64\x64" -x cu   -I"
  D:\AIGC\tiny-cuda-nn\include" -I"D:\AIGC\tiny-cuda-nn\dependencies" -I"D:\AIGC\tiny-cuda-nn\dependencies\cutlass\incl
  ude" -I"D:\AIGC\tiny-cuda-nn\dependencies\cutlass\tools\util\include" -I"D:\AIGC\tiny-cuda-nn\dependencies\fmt\includ
  e" -I"C:\Program Files\NVIDIA GPU Computing Toolkit\CUDA\v11.8\include"     --keep-dir x64\RelWithDebInfo  -maxrregco
  unt=0  --machine 64 --compile -cudart static -std=c++14 --generate-code=arch=compute_86,code=[compute_86,sm_86] --ext
  ended-lambda --expt-relaxed-constexpr -Xcompiler="/EHsc -Zi -Ob1 /bigobj"   -D_WINDOWS -DNDEBUG -DTCNN_MIN_GPU_ARCH=8
  6 -D"CMAKE_INTDIR=\"RelWithDebInfo\"" -D_MBCS -DWIN32 -D_WINDOWS -D_CRT_SECURE_NO_WARNINGS -DNDEBUG -DTCNN_MIN_GPU_AR
  CH=86 -D"CMAKE_INTDIR=\"RelWithDebInfo\"" -Xcompiler "/EHsc /W1 /nologo /O2 /FdD:\AIGC\tiny-cuda-nn\build\RelWithDebI
  nfo\tiny-cuda-nn.pdb /FS /Zi  /MD /GR" -o tiny-cuda-nn.dir\RelWithDebInfo\optimizer.obj "D:\AIGC\tiny-cuda-nn\src\opt
  imizer.cu"
D:\AIGC\tiny-cuda-nn\dependencies\cutlass\include\cutlass/platform/platform.h(845): warning #68-D: integer conversion r
esulted in a change of sign [D:\AIGC\tiny-cuda-nn\build\tiny-cuda-nn.vcxproj]

D:\AIGC\tiny-cuda-nn\dependencies\cutlass\include\cutlass/platform/platform.h(845): warning #68-D: integer conversion r
esulted in a change of sign [D:\AIGC\tiny-cuda-nn\build\tiny-cuda-nn.vcxproj]

  common_host.cu
  reduce_sum.cu
  object.cu
  cpp_api.cu
  network.cu
  loss.cu
  optimizer.cu
D:\AIGC\tiny-cuda-nn\dependencies\cutlass\include\cutlass/platform/platform.h(845): warning #68-D: integer conversion r
esulted in a change of sign [D:\AIGC\tiny-cuda-nn\build\tiny-cuda-nn.vcxproj]

  cutlass_mlp.cu
  encoding.cu
D:\AIGC\tiny-cuda-nn\dependencies\cutlass\include\cutlass/platform/platform.h(845): warning #68-D: integer conversion r
esulted in a change of sign [D:\AIGC\tiny-cuda-nn\build\tiny-cuda-nn.vcxproj]

  fully_fused_mlp.cu
  tiny-cuda-nn.vcxproj -> D:\AIGC\tiny-cuda-nn\build\RelWithDebInfo\tiny-cuda-nn.lib
  Building Custom Rule D:/AIGC/tiny-cuda-nn/benchmarks/image/CMakeLists.txt
  Building Custom Rule D:/AIGC/tiny-cuda-nn/samples/CMakeLists.txt
  Compiling CUDA source file ..\..\..\benchmarks\image\bench_ours.cu...
  Compiling CUDA source file ..\..\samples\mlp_learning_an_image.cu...


  D:\AIGC\tiny-cuda-nn\build\samples>"C:\Program Files\NVIDIA GPU Computing Toolkit\CUDA\v11.8\bin\nvcc.exe"  --use-loc
  al-env -ccbin "D:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio\2022\Community\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.38.33130\bin\HostX64\x64" -x
  cu   -I"D:\AIGC\tiny-cuda-nn\include" -I"D:\AIGC\tiny-cuda-nn\dependencies" -I"D:\AIGC\tiny-cuda-nn\dependencies\cutl
  ass\include" -I"D:\AIGC\tiny-cuda-nn\dependencies\cutlass\tools\util\include" -I"D:\AIGC\tiny-cuda-nn\dependencies\fm
  t\include" -I"C:\Program Files\NVIDIA GPU Computing Toolkit\CUDA\v11.8\include"     --keep-dir x64\RelWithDebInfo  -m
  axrregcount=0  --machine 64 --compile -cudart static -std=c++14 --generate-code=arch=compute_86,code=[compute_86,sm_8
  6] --extended-lambda --expt-relaxed-constexpr -Xcompiler="/EHsc -Zi -Ob1 /bigobj"   -D_WINDOWS -DNDEBUG -DTCNN_MIN_GP
  U_ARCH=86 -D"CMAKE_INTDIR=\"RelWithDebInfo\"" -D_MBCS -DWIN32 -D_WINDOWS -D_CRT_SECURE_NO_WARNINGS -DNDEBUG -DTCNN_MI
  N_GPU_ARCH=86 -D"CMAKE_INTDIR=\"RelWithDebInfo\"" -Xcompiler "/EHsc /W1 /nologo /O2 /Fdmlp_learning_an_image.dir\RelW
  ithDebInfo\vc143.pdb /FS /Zi  /MD /GR" -o mlp_learning_an_image.dir\RelWithDebInfo\mlp_learning_an_image.obj "D:\AIGC
  \tiny-cuda-nn\samples\mlp_learning_an_image.cu"
  D:\AIGC\tiny-cuda-nn\build\benchmarks\image>"C:\Program Files\NVIDIA GPU Computing Toolkit\CUDA\v11.8\bin\nvcc.exe"
  --use-local-env -ccbin "D:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio\2022\Community\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.38.33130\bin\HostX64
  \x64" -x cu   -I"D:\AIGC\tiny-cuda-nn\include" -I"D:\AIGC\tiny-cuda-nn\dependencies" -I"D:\AIGC\tiny-cuda-nn\dependen
  cies\cutlass\include" -I"D:\AIGC\tiny-cuda-nn\dependencies\cutlass\tools\util\include" -I"D:\AIGC\tiny-cuda-nn\depend
  encies\fmt\include" -I"C:\Program Files\NVIDIA GPU Computing Toolkit\CUDA\v11.8\include"     --keep-dir x64\RelWithDe
  bInfo  -maxrregcount=0  --machine 64 --compile -cudart static -std=c++14 --generate-code=arch=compute_86,code=[comput
  e_86,sm_86] --extended-lambda --expt-relaxed-constexpr -Xcompiler="/EHsc -Zi -Ob1 /bigobj"   -D_WINDOWS -DNDEBUG -DTC
  NN_MIN_GPU_ARCH=86 -D"CMAKE_INTDIR=\"RelWithDebInfo\"" -D_MBCS -DWIN32 -D_WINDOWS -D_CRT_SECURE_NO_WARNINGS -DNDEBUG
  -DTCNN_MIN_GPU_ARCH=86 -D"CMAKE_INTDIR=\"RelWithDebInfo\"" -Xcompiler "/EHsc /W1 /nologo /O2 /Fdbench_image_ours.dir\
  RelWithDebInfo\vc143.pdb /FS /Zi  /MD /GR" -o bench_image_ours.dir\RelWithDebInfo\bench_ours.obj "D:\AIGC\tiny-cuda-n
  n\benchmarks\image\bench_ours.cu"
  mlp_learning_an_image.cu
  bench_ours.cu
  stbi_wrapper.cpp
  stbi_wrapper.cpp
     Creating library D:/AIGC/tiny-cuda-nn/build/samples/RelWithDebInfo/mlp_learning_an_image.lib and object D:/AIGC/ti
  ny-cuda-nn/build/samples/RelWithDebInfo/mlp_learning_an_image.exp
     Creating library D:/AIGC/tiny-cuda-nn/build/benchmarks/image/RelWithDebInfo/bench_image_ours.lib and object D:/AIG
  C/tiny-cuda-nn/build/benchmarks/image/RelWithDebInfo/bench_image_ours.exp
LINK : warning LNK4098: defaultlib 'LIBCMT' conflicts with use of other libs; use /NODEFAULTLIB:library [D:\AIGC\tiny-c
uda-nn\build\samples\mlp_learning_an_image.vcxproj]
LINK : warning LNK4098: defaultlib 'LIBCMT' conflicts with use of other libs; use /NODEFAULTLIB:library [D:\AIGC\tiny-c
uda-nn\build\benchmarks\image\bench_image_ours.vcxproj]
  bench_image_ours.vcxproj -> D:\AIGC\tiny-cuda-nn\build\bench_image_ours.exe
  mlp_learning_an_image.vcxproj -> D:\AIGC\tiny-cuda-nn\build\mlp_learning_an_image.exe
  Building Custom Rule D:/AIGC/tiny-cuda-nn/CMakeLists.txt
```

**then go to vscode powershell terminal**

`cd D:\AIGC\tiny-cuda-nn\bindings\torch`

`& d:/AIGC/threestudio/venv/Scripts/python.exe setup.py install`

Here is the log:

```
PS D:\AIGC\tiny-cuda-nn\bindings\torch> & d:/AIGC/threestudio/venv/Scripts/python.exe setup.py install
D:\AIGC\tiny-cuda-nn\bindings\torch\setup.py:5: DeprecationWarning: pkg_resources is deprecated as an API. See https://setuptools.pypa.io/en/latest/pkg_resources.html
  from pkg_resources import parse_version
Building PyTorch extension for tiny-cuda-nn version 1.7
Obtained compute capability 86 from PyTorch
nvcc: NVIDIA (R) Cuda compiler driver
Copyright (c) 2005-2022 NVIDIA Corporation
Built on Wed_Sep_21_10:41:10_Pacific_Daylight_Time_2022
Cuda compilation tools, release 11.8, V11.8.89
Build cuda_11.8.r11.8/compiler.31833905_0
Detected CUDA version 11.8
Targeting C++ standard 17
running install


D:/Windows Kits/10/Include/10.0.22621.0/ucrt\fenv.h(113): warning #550-D: variable "_Ans" was set but never used

D:/AIGC/tiny-cuda-nn/dependencies/cutlass/include\cutlass/platform/platform.h(845): warning #68-D: integer conversion resulted in a change of sign

fully_fused_mlp.cu
creating D:\AIGC\tiny-cuda-nn\bindings\torch\build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-310\tinycudann_bindings
"D:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio\2022\Community\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.38.33130\bin\Hostx64\x64\link.exe" /nologo /INCREMENTAL:NO /LTCG /DLL /MANIFEST:EMBED,ID=2 /MANIFESTUAC:NO /LIBPATH:D:\AIGC\threestudio\venv\lib\site-packages\torch\lib "/LIBPATH:C:\Program Files\NVIDIA GPU Computing Toolkit\CUDA\v11.8\lib\x64" /LIBPATH:D:\AIGC\threestudio\venv\libs /LIBPATH:C:\Python310\libs /LIBPATH:C:\Python310 /LIBPATH:D:\AIGC\threestudio\venv\PCbuild\amd64 "/LIBPATH:D:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio\2022\Community\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.38.33130\lib" "/LIBPATH:D:\Windows Kits\10\Lib\10.0.22621.0\ucrt\x64" "/LIBPATH:D:\Windows Kits\10\Lib\10.0.22621.0\ucrt_enclave\x64" "/LIBPATH:D:\Windows Kits\10\Lib\10.0.22621.0\um\x64" cuda.lib c10.lib torch.lib torch_cpu.lib torch_python.lib cudart.lib c10_cuda.lib torch_cuda.lib /EXPORT:PyInit__86_C D:\AIGC\tiny-cuda-nn\bindings\torch\build\temp.win-amd64-cpython-310\Release\../../dependencies/fmt/src/format.obj D:\AIGC\tiny-cuda-nn\bindings\torch\build\temp.win-amd64-cpython-310\Release\../../dependencies/fmt/src/os.obj D:\AIGC\tiny-cuda-nn\bindings\torch\build\temp.win-amd64-cpython-310\Release\../../src/common_host.obj D:\AIGC\tiny-cuda-nn\bindings\torch\build\temp.win-amd64-cpython-310\Release\../../src/cpp_api.obj D:\AIGC\tiny-cuda-nn\bindings\torch\build\temp.win-amd64-cpython-310\Release\../../src/cutlass_mlp.obj D:\AIGC\tiny-cuda-nn\bindings\torch\build\temp.win-amd64-cpython-310\Release\../../src/encoding.obj D:\AIGC\tiny-cuda-nn\bindings\torch\build\temp.win-amd64-cpython-310\Release\../../src/fully_fused_mlp.obj D:\AIGC\tiny-cuda-nn\bindings\torch\build\temp.win-amd64-cpython-310\Release\../../src/network.obj D:\AIGC\tiny-cuda-nn\bindings\torch\build\temp.win-amd64-cpython-310\Release\../../src/object.obj D:\AIGC\tiny-cuda-nn\bindings\torch\build\temp.win-amd64-cpython-310\Release\tinycudann/bindings.obj /OUT:build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-310\tinycudann_bindings\_86_C.cp310-win_amd64.pyd /IMPLIB:D:\AIGC\tiny-cuda-nn\bindings\torch\build\temp.win-amd64-cpython-310\Release\../../dependencies/fmt/src\_86_C.cp310-win_amd64.lib
LINK : fatal error LNK1104: cannot open file 'msvcprt.lib'
error: command 'D:\\Program Files\\Microsoft Visual Studio\\2022\\Community\\VC\\Tools\\MSVC\\14.38.33130\\bin\\Hostx64\\x64\\link.exe' failed with exit code 1104
```

How can I fix this?